# efficiently finding prime numbers in python

Tags: python, math

here is my code:

```
def findPrimes():
   prime=True
   c=0
   n=1
   while n<14:
        n=n+1
        for i in range(1,n):
            if n%i==0:
                prime=False
        if prime==True:
            print(n)
   while c==0:
        n=n+1
        if (n%2==0) or (n%3==0) or (n%5==0)or (n%7==0)or (n%11==0)or (n%13==0):
            c=0#this does nothing
        else:
            for i in range(5,int(n**0.5),2):
                if n%i==0:
                    break
            print(n)
findPrimes()
```

it should output:
2
3
5
7
11
13
17
...
Instead, I get:
17
19
23
29
31
37
41
43
47
...
or(with break in a different indent):
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
17
19
...
why is this?

Comment: You second while is indented incorrectly. Please edit your question and fix the indentation first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Sieve of Eratosthenes an efficient way to find all primes. It is proven that you only have to check up to sqrt(n) items.

```
def primes_sieve2(limit):
a = [True] * limit                   # Initialize the primalitylist
a[0] = a[1] = False

for (i, isprime) in enumerate(a):
    if isprime:
        yield i
        for n in xrange(i*i, limit, i):     # Mark factors non-prime
            a[n] = False
```

Comment: keep in mind the Sieve of Eratosthenes is memory limited though. It's great for most general purposes, but when you get into security / encryption, etc. with increasingly massive primes, you might start looking at things like the Miller-Rabin primality test.

Comment: The SoE is not remotely the fastest way to find all primes. You should alter your statement.

Answer (score 3):

The best efficient way to find the Prime numbers is to use the **Sieve of Eratosthenes** algorithm.

Here is the code:

```
n = int(input("enter the number upto which to find: "))
sieve = set(range(2, n+1))
while sieve:
    prime = min(sieve)
    print(prime, end="\t")
    sieve -= set(range(prime, n+1, prime))
print()
```

Explanation:

- First, get the upper limit of the range
- A variable of `set` type is assigned to eliminate the duplicates
- As we know 0,1 are not prime numbers, so we don't count them i.e (2,n+1)
- We take minimum element as prime and print it
- Now, if 2 is prime, all of the multiples of 2 cannot be prime. So we neglect the multiples of 2. Same as the following 3,5,7 etc...
- So, all the remaining numbers are added to sieve i.e the remaining numbers are prime numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way to find prime numbers is this:

```
def prime(nums,no_of_recursion):
  if(nums):
    print(min(nums),end=", ")
    nums-=set(range(min(nums), max(nums)+1, min(nums)))
    no_of_recursion=no_of_recursion+1
    prime(nums,no_of_recursion)
  else:
    print('\nTotal recursions: '+str(no_of_recursion))


limit=101
no_of_recursion=0
nums=set(range(2,limit+1))
prime(nums,no_of_recursion)
```

Output:

```
2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 
Total recursions: 26
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this block of code:

```
while n<14:
        n=n+1
        for i in range(1,n):
            if n%i==0:
                prime=False
```

prime will be equal to false for every iteration there because

x % 1 == 0 for all x

Answer (score 0):

this is all you need.

```
def primes(n):
        primeslist = [2]
        for i in range (2,n):
            p = 1
            for j in primeslist:

                if (i%j) == 0:
                    p = 0
                    break
            if p == 1:
                primeslist.append(i)
        return primeslist

    primeslist = primes(66)
    print(primeslist)
```

NOTES:

- you only need to check division by all previous primes in the list to find whether a number is prime.
- is prime flag should be set before second loop.
- n is the number that you want to stop checking for primes at. otherwise your program will go on forever.
- computing primes can only be so efficient. I found primes (99999) in about 7 seconds on my setup.
- You can further limit the algorithm to checking only 1 to sqrt(n) for divisibility.

> ```
> primeslist = primes(66)
> print(primeslist)
>
> [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61]
> ```

Comment: You also don't need to check any prime in the list > sqrt(n). See [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Algorithm_and_variants)

Comment: that's correct. However in python making that optimization actually save you time is non-trivial. Naive implementations of that optimization ended up actually making my code run slower. I didn't want to add too much complexity, only to show the basic algorithm. Still, thanks for the note.

Comment: It's a pretty good optimization especially as N gets larger. My suggestion: try it both ways and see the difference.  E.g https://projecteuler.net/problem=7

Comment: I suppose at what point it actually becomes faster depends on implementation. If you do it wrong, it will be much slower than without the optimization. I couldn't think of anything that was fast enough, without hurting code readability too much. I tried to make my example as clear as possible for learning purposes.

Comment: This is an important optimization for all but trivial values of N. Here is a [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZBNCsIwEIX3OcWACAmItLUgCPUi4qLS1E5t0jiNC08fk9Ta1iwC8@abNz/mbZteZ85tauoVqNI2gMr0ZGF4kmWVrMEQKjlwLU4M/BvDDgcLBVyyaxQ3HSoMQqjyaBTrngABNVCp7xJ4tps8oo@n018U2Daws/2Mxg5YQ3uObf4S4buRLB8r2eMct62AooBkXTF1T9gCNgFM1@A8y740RuqK47gZSfui5ayMrc7yPVma5Mf8IEJOW95JzWdKCOc@ "Python 2 – Try It Online") which passes the solution to Euler problem 7 (104743) to your primes function.  It took `Real time: 36.500 s` to run.  With this optimization (uncomment the '#' lines) it takes `Real time: 0.795 s`.

Comment: um, yeah, that makes sense. For some reason I was trying something ridiculous with list notation. But shouldn't you define limit inside the first forloop? Otherwise it's just going to  stop calculating sooner.

Comment: The limit is a function of n, which doesn't change in the loop.  Also in your function you should add a `break` right after `p = 0` because after that point there's no need to keep testing other factors.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Efficient way of Prime number -------->>>>>
try:
    num = int(input('Enter number : '))
    if(num>1):
        for i in range(2,num):
            if (num%i==0):
                print(f'{num} is not a Prime Number...!')
                break
        else:
            print(f'{num} is a Prime Number...!')
    elif num==0:
        print(f'{num} is conpositive number')
    elif num == 1:
        print(f"{num} is not considered as prime or composite")
    else:
        print('Invalid input')
except:
    print('Invalid input')
```

Answer (score 0):

Many solutions are pointing you to the sieve algorihim.

However, if you're needing a simple brute-force implementation you can write your code much more cleanly which will make finding errors and mistakes much easier.

Here's a cleaner brute-force implmentation:

```
num = 11
  
# If given number is greater than 1
if num > 1:
  
    # Iterate from 2 to n / 2
    for i in range(2, int(num/2)+1):
  
        # If num is divisible by any number between
        # 2 and n / 2, it is not prime
        if (num % i) == 0:
            print(num, "is not a prime number")
            break
    else:
        print(num, "is a prime number")
  
else:
    print(num, "is not a prime number")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
nums = int(input("enter the number "))
for i in range(2,nums):
    if nums % i  == 0:
        print("Its not a prime no ")
        break
else:
    print("prime no ")
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to check a number is prime or not , let's check the number 13.

```
a = 13
for b in range(2,a) :
    if a % b == 0 :
        print("not prime")
        break
    else :
        print("prime")
```